# operators ? and : with boolean and void

Tags: java, if-statement, logical-operators

I am trying to figure out how to use operators ? : instead if else block

My case is below:

```
if (boolean variable) {
void1(); }
else {
void2();
}
```

is it possible to do this by that way:

```
boolean variable ? void1() : void2();
```

I was looking for an answer but I cannot find it with boolean and call void method

Comment: The ternary operator is not a replacement for if-else statements. It is used for assignments and doesn't work with void methods.

Comment: No, you can't put methods returning void into this kind of construction.  Just use `if` and `else`.

Comment: See the difference between expressions and statements in Java : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/expressions.html

Answer (score -2):

This will not work, as it is not the intended use of the ternary operator.Ternary operators will be used for assignments.

If you really want it to be 1 line, you can write:

```
if (boolean variable) void1(); else void2();
```